# Decrypt string in php which was encrypted with aspEncrypt

Tags: php, mcrypt, encryption

I need to communicate with a asp platform that uses the aspEncrypt from persits.
Can anyone provide an example how to decode a string with PHP and mcrypt that was created via the aspEncrypt routines.

An example page of aspEncrypt is available at this link:
http://support.persits.com/encrypt/demo_text.asp

So if I use the text "Test" and the key "test" it provides an base64 encoded string. I need a php example that convert this encoded string back to the text "Test" with usage of key "test".

Comment: Which cipher is the asp script using?

Comment: It uses RC2, but you can select which cipher it should be. But it does not matter which cipher I use, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i finally solved it:

Expectation:

- Key is known
- IV is known (in my case, first 32 characters of encoded data)
- Encrypted Text is known

In my special case all received data hex encoded.
This means IV and encrypted text.

```
function decrypt($sString, $sIv, $sKey, $iCipherAlg) {       
   $sDecrypted = mcrypt_decrypt($iCipherAlg, $sKey, $sString, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $sIv);
    return trim($sDecrypted);
}

function hex2bin($sData) {
    $iLen = strlen($sData);
    $sNewData = '';
    for($iCount=0;$iCount<$iLen;$iCount+=2) {
        $sNewData .= pack("C",hexdec(substr($sData,$iCount,2)));
    }
    return $sNewData;
} 

$sKey = 'this is my key';
// first 32 chars are IV
$sIv = hex2bin(substr($sEncodedData, 0, 32));
$sEncodedData = substr($sEncodedData, 32);
$sEncodedRaw = hex2bin($sEncodedData);
$sDecrypted = decrypt($sEncodedRaw, $sIv, $sKey, MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128);
```

A corresponding encryption works like that:

```
$sIv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
$sKey = 'this is my key';
$sContent = 'a lot of content';
$sEncrypted = bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $sKey, $sContent, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $sIv));
$sFullEncodedText = bin2hex($sIv) . $sEncrypted;
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an old VBScript project which was encrypting strings with AspEncrypt like this:

```vb
Function EncryptString(data, base64Iv)
    Set CM = Server.CreateObject("Persits.CryptoManager")
    Set Context = CM.OpenContextEx("Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider", "", True)
    Set Key = Context.GenerateKeyFromPassword("secret encryption password", calgSHA512, calgAES256)

    Set IVblob = CM.CreateBlob
    IVblob.Base64 = base64Iv
    Key.SetIV IVblob

    Set Blob = Key.EncryptText(data)
    EncryptString = Blob.Base64 & ":" & base64Iv
End Function
```

Based on the arguments to `GenerateKeyFromPassword`, a binary key is created by hashing the password with SHA-512, and data is encrypted with the aes-256-cbc algorithm. The random Base64-encoded initialization vector is appended to the encrypted value after a colon.

This can be replicated in PHP using the OpenSSL extension:

```php
class Aes256Cbc
{
    private string $algo = 'aes-256-cbc';
    private string $key;
    private int $ivLen;

    public function __construct(string $password)
    {
        $this->key = hash('sha512', $password, true);
        $this->ivLen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->algo);
    }

    public function encrypt(string $data): string
    {
        $iv = random_bytes($this->ivLen);
        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($data, $this->algo, $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        return base64_encode($ciphertext) . ':' . base64_encode($iv);
    }

    public function decrypt(string $encrypted): string
    {
        [$ctPart, $ivPart] = explode(':', $encrypted);
        $iv = base64_decode($ivPart);
        $ciphertext = base64_decode($ctPart);
        return openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $this->algo, $this->key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```php
$aes = new Aes256Cbc("secret encryption password");
$decrypted = $aes->decrypt($someValue);
```

Note: if AspEncrypt was used without setting an initialization vector, the IV will be sequence of null bytes. This fixed IV could be generated in the above PHP class as follows:

```php
$iv = str_repeat("\0", $this->ivLen);
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which cipher it uses, take a look at [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) as long as you know the cipher and key it should be easy to decrypt.

Comment: No chance. Just try it on your own. Open the link, enter a key and a text, choose a cipher and try to decrypt the resut with php

Answer (score -1):

If you know the cipher and mode used by the encryption, the function `mcrypt_decrypt` can decrypt it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php

Comment: I know everything which is necessary (Key, Cipher, etc.)  but it seems, that aspencrypt create the key somehow different.
Has anybody got an experience with this special aspEncrypt module?